# Error when i try to debug SharePoint app using ngrok "The endpoint address http://****.svc does not match the app's endpoint localhost:44327"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, ngrok

I want to develop and debug a sharepoint remote event receiver. previously we use to debug the RER using azure service bus, but recently using azure service bus was depreciated by Microsoft and can not be used anymore to debug our remote event receivers. and the alternative is to use a revere proxy named Ngrok. but i am facing some problems, which did not happen when i were using the azure service bus for debugging.

Here is a full description about my case:-

1) Inside our sharepoint online i created a new developer site collection.

2) Using Visual Studio pro 2015 >> i created a new Visual Studio project of type SP Add-in.

3) I selected the Type = Provider-hosted, as follow:-
[image]

4) After that i changed the Handle Add-in installed/uninstalled to True:-
[image]

5) Then i open the Ngrok command line, i enter the following:-

> ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 50452// where this port is our RER
>   port inside visual studio

- Where 50452 is the port for the VS project:-
  [image]
- I got the following:-
  [image]
- So i updated the `AppManifest.xml` with the forwarding url:-
  [image]

6) I update the app permission as follow:-
[image]

7) Then i run the project >> i got this popup >> i select the custom list named "projects":-
[image]

8) Where i got to the break-point inside my code >> but the `clientContent` inside my code will be `null`:-
[image]

9) After that the VS stop running and i got this error:-
[image]

Here is the full code inside my "AppEventReceiver.svc"

```
public class AppEventReceiver : IRemoteEventService
    {
        private const string ReceiverName = "ItemAddedEvent";
        private const string ListName = "projects";
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles app events that occur after the app is installed or upgraded, or when app is being uninstalled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties">Holds information about the app event.</param>
        /// <returns>Holds information returned from the app event.</returns>
        public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

            switch (properties.EventType)
            {
                case SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled:
                    HandleAppInstalled(properties);
                    break;
                case SPRemoteEventType.AppUninstalling:
                    HandleAppUninstalling(properties);
                    break;
                case SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded:
                    HandleItemAdded(properties);
                    break;
            }


            return result;
        }
        private void HandleAppUninstalling(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)

        {

            using (ClientContext clientContext =

              TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))

            {

                if (clientContext != null)

                {

                    List myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);

                    clientContext.Load(myList, p => p.EventReceivers);

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                    var rer = myList.EventReceivers.Where(

                        e => e.ReceiverName == ReceiverName).FirstOrDefault();



                    try

                    {

                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Removing ItemAdded receiver at "

                               + rer.ReceiverUrl);



                        //This will fail when deploying via F5, but works

                        //when deployed to production

                        rer.DeleteObject();

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                    }

                    catch (Exception oops)

                    {

                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(oops.Message);

                    }



                }

            }

        }
        private void HandleAppInstalled(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)

        {

            using (ClientContext clientContext =

                 TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))

            {

                if (clientContext != null)

                {

                    List myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);

                    clientContext.Load(myList, p => p.EventReceivers);

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                    bool rerExists = false;



                    foreach (var rer in myList.EventReceivers)

                    {

                        if (rer.ReceiverName == ReceiverName)
                        {

                            rerExists = true;

                            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Found existing ItemAdded receiver at "

                                + rer.ReceiverUrl);

                        }

                    }



                    if (!rerExists)

                    {

                        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver =

                             new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();

                        receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;


                        //Get WCF URL where this message was handled

                        OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
                        Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;



                        receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();



                        receiver.ReceiverName = ReceiverName;

                        receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
                        myList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);



                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Added ItemAdded receiver at "

                                + msg.Headers.To.ToString());

                    }

                }

            }

        }
        private void HandleItemAdded(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)

        {

            using (ClientContext clientContext =

                 TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))

            {

                if (clientContext != null)

                {

                    try

                    {

                        List photos = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(

                              properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);

                        ListItem item = photos.GetItemById(

                             properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);

                        clientContext.Load(item);

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                        item["Title"] += "\nUpdated by RER " +

                               System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

                        item.Update();

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    }

                    catch (Exception oops)

                    {

                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(oops.Message);

                    }

                }



            }



        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is a required placeholder, but is not used by app events.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties">Unused.</param>
        public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

**Question-1.** So can anyone advice why i am getting Null for the `ClientContext` ? and why the project will stop running?

10) I also added a break-point inside the `TokenHelper.cs`, and the `properties` inside the  `return CreateAcsClientContextForUrl(properties, sharepointUrl);` will have the following error:-

> The endpoint address
>   'http://4bb34796.ngrok.io/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc' does not
>   match the app's endpoint 'localhost:44327'.

[image]

**Question-2.** Also i am not sure why i am getting that the port will be `44327` inside the above error, although in my case the VS project have a port = `50452` as shown in the above picture?? and i used the `50452` port inside the Ngrok command line `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 50452`

**Can anyone advice on my above 2 questions?**

Thanks

Comment: any help on this issue?

Comment: It seems like a complicated issue, but regarding the Question 2 the port 44327  is for the SSL configuration in your project. So maybe check the configurations that you are not "forcing" SSL with code.

Comment: @theCuriousOne  i am not forcing SSL inside my code. also i disable SSL from the project properties. Then i run the project , but i got the same exception, but this time for the http port a follow `The endpoint address 'http://6ad2ebe4.ngrok.io/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc' does not match the app's endpoint 'localhost:50452'.`

Comment: @theCuriousOne yes when i wrote the second question i have already run a newer ngrok command. i updated my question to match the 2 ngrok addresses , thanks for the note. for your second note, i did not understand what do u exactly mean, can u provide more info please?

Comment: @theCuriousOne so you mean i should not add the ngrok address inside my AppManifest.xml ? by defualt the AppManifest.xml will have this settings `~remoteAppUrl/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc` ,, so should  i keep it as-is?

Comment: @theCuriousOne ok i revert back the address on the AppManifest.xml, but in this case the app will not even get installed inside the sharepoint site + i will not get any break-point to be reached inside my code.. so i think the AppManifest.xml should be updated to match the ngrok addresses, otherwise there will be no link between my code and the ngrok address...

Comment: @theCuriousOne so my main problem is why i am getting this error "The endpoint address 'http://****.ngrok.io/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc' does not match the app's endpoint 'localhost:50452'.".. so my VS project has `50452` port, while inside the AppManifest.xml i define the ngrok address, but the ngrok address is based on the VS port i specified inside th ngrok code  `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 50452`.. now i do not know 100% how Ngrok works, but i think i am setting everything correctly...

Comment: ngrok provides a sort of a tunnel though some restricted intranet, or in other words it creates a vpn with your local computer and the public internet. For example, if you are on a company network all the computers of your company has 1 outside address (usually). So ngrok provides a way to make a way to expose just your computer to the accessible publicly. (cont.)

Comment: I may have misunderstood something before. You have a share point application hosted on Azure. You call that application somehow, and you what to inspect what exactly it is happening to your sharepoint application (to debug). Right? 

If that is the case then I am not sure that the approach with ngrok is valid (since it is mainly for local usage) and Azure might be blocking it.

I haven't done remote debugging with Azure, but did some googling and found this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/ (which might help you).

Comment: @theCuriousOne i am developing a remote event receiver (which is mainly a provider hosted app), previously we were able to test and debug our RER, by writing the VS code and define the azure service bus for debugging, this will allow us to test our sharepoint app and define breakpoints inside our code. now the azure service bus appraoch has been deprecated 1 year ago, and we were advised to use Ngrok instead of azure service bus

Comment: @theCuriousOne ... so my sharepoint app at this stage is not inside azure, i am running it inside sharepoint development site.. after finishing my development , i will deploy the service to azure and the app to our sharepoint app catalog site...

Comment: @theCuriousOne i were developing around 30 RERs by following the steps in this link @ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ but these steps will no longer work, as the azure service bus has been depreciated, and without been able to debug our code, we can not work on developing any thing...

Comment: @theCuriousOne inside this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/debug-and-troubleshoot-a-remote-event-receiver-in-a-sharepoint-add-in check the "closed" issues tab, someone mentioned why MS is providing this documentation `Also when the feature gets deprecated, would you really mind updating the documentation so developer's time is not wasted?`:)

Comment: @theCuriousOne here is a question inside MSDN https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6606300a-426f-4dec-97a7-ba76caec0ff3/one-or-more-services-were-unregistered-from-the-microsoft-azure-service-bus-cannot-register?forum=onlineservicessharepoint#7f497888-0ffd-47d4-89a4-fa7ac6ef9b19 where it mentioned that this appraoch is retired. and you can see the error i got when i used the azure service bus `One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus.` now i do not want to turn this question into approving that azure service bus is retried or not.thanks